# How long does it take for Ubuntu One to sync my files?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Just got Nattey Narwhal on my laptop yesterday and thought of using U1 cloud with my netbook instead of good old scp. Just copied the required stuff into /home/username/Ubuntu One in my netbook and was expecting to see the stuff synced in the desktop right away. Nothing of that sort. Almost two hours later I get a popup saying that the files are getting downloaded. How long does it take on average?

Comment: Note that [over the next few weeks then Ubuntu One file syncs will be increasing by as much as 400 times](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=906)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple options for getting more info to help you determine how long your sync is taking.

**u1sdtool**

From the command line you can get the number of items in the queue with this command run in the terminal:

```
u1sdtool --waiting | wc -l
```

Overtime the number will get smaller as files are uploaded/downloaded.

**magicicada**

[image: Magicicada Screenshot]

There is also a project called [Magicicada](https://launchpad.net/magicicada) that is a GUI for the Ubuntu One syncdaemon. It allows you to connect/disconnect and see the queue. You can install it with these commands in a terminal.

add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:chicharreros/ppa
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install magicicada
```

You can launch the application by opening the Dash and typing 'Magi'. In pre Natty releases you can launch the application by going to Applications > Accessories > Magicicada

Answer (score 1):

Its going to take awhile depending on how many files you have(size doesn't matter). I myself, synced my Music folder(14gb) to U1. At first it seemed as if there were errors but then I googled around. If you want to see progress on files being uploaded go to synaptic or apt-get(which ever you prefer and install "magicicada". Like I said, 14gb Music folder took me almost 2 days. But magicicada let me see progress.